# SharedPreferences not working, when try to get in another Activity

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I have this code:

```
SharedPreferences settings = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putString("allphones",allphones);
editor.putString("specialkey", someKey);
editor.commit();
```

The allphones parameter gets stored, but when I try to get the "specialkey" in the next Activity like this:

```
String allphones = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getString("specialkey","Blabla");
```

It ALWAYS returns me the Default String "Blabla".

Comment: are you sure someKey is not null when you put the preference ?

Comment: @SebastienRieu 100% sure

Comment: `getPreferences()` returns a `SharedPreferences` that is specific to a given `Activity`, so your second `Activity` is reading from a completely different file than the one that the first `Activity` saved to. Use `getSharedPreferences()` instead, where you can specify the filename, or possibly `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences()`, which uses a single default filename throughout your app.

Comment: @MikeM. ^^ should be an answer and not a comment!

Comment: @Alex I've already closed it as a duplicate.

Comment: @MikeM. Need my coffee LOL